# Firebase Firestore SDK will not run with Mocha+Chai unit tests

Tags: node.js, firebase, unit-testing, google-cloud-firestore, mocha.js

### **Issue**:

When running a test in Mocha, we need to add a document to the local emulated Firestore.  The local emulated setup is working **but not within the Mocha test**, specifically.

> Node Version: `14.18.1`, chai: `4.3.4`, firebase-admin: `10.0.0`, firebase: `9.1.3`

### **Explaination**

- Working Locally:

  If I were to try and run:
  `await conref.doc('testDoc').set({test: true});` before the first Mocha
  `describe()`, I can verify the document is added to my local Firestore at
  `localhost:8080`

  ```
  const db = getFirestore();
  const ref = db.collection('testCollection');
  await ref.doc('testDoc').set({test: true});
  const testDoc = await db.collection('testCollection').doc('testDoc').get();
  console.log(testDoc.data());
  ```

  > prints `{ test: true }`, confirming packages and connection is working
- Breaking In Mocha:

  ..however placing similar logic inside my `describe()` causes the test to report as
  errored each and every time, returning a red `(1)` instead of a green checkmark:

  ```
  describe("example", async function() {
    it("should write to Firestore in a mocha test", async function() {
      const db = getFirestore();
      const ref = db.collection('testCollection');
      await ref.doc('testDoc').set({test: true});  // < causes error
    };
  };
  ```

  screenshot

  [image]

### **Imports**

Firebase has had different version and its been confusing, so I will include the imports I am using for both of these examples below, in case this might be very wrong.

```
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase-admin/firestore';
import { initializeApp, applicationDefault } from 'firebase-admin/app';

initializeApp({
  credential: applicationDefault(),
  databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASAE_URL,  
});
```

### **Attempts**

- Tried adjusting timeouts, thinking maybe the Mocha suite was not waiting for the doc to be added, but even an addition of `this.timeout(10000);` within the test did not change the outcome.
- Tried setting the doc *before* the test, which worked, so I put this in a function and tried calling it from within the test as if I was praying on a Hail Mary, but to no surprise this had no effect.
- Tried connecting to my production Firestore but still no cigar (via removing the `FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST` env).
- Added `done()` at the end of the test, but did not change outcome